# How to append child divs to parent divs by selecting on ids from a data file

Tags: d3.js

I have html in this structure:

```
<div id="typeA"></div>
<div id="typeB"></div>
```

and a table of data such as:

```
[["#typeA","someValue"],
 ["#typeA","anotherValue"],
 ["#typeB","thirdValue"]]
```

and I think it's possible to use d3.js to append the values as text inside child div of each of the present divs like so:

```
<div id="typeA">
    <div>someValue</div>
    <div>anotherValue</div>
</div>
<div id="typeB">
    <div>thirdValue</div>
</div>
```

Would this need a nest()?

fyi this didn't work for reasons that are now obvious to me:

```
var body = d3.select("body")
    .data(matrix)
    .enter()
    .select(function(d) {return d[0]}).
    .data(this)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .text(function(d) {return d[1]});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 isn't ideal in this case because your document is not entirely data-driven -- you already have elements that need to be matched to the data in a non-D3 fashion. You can however emulate what D3 does and "bind" the data to the existing elements manually:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  var elem = d3.select(d[0]).node();
  if(elem.__data__ === undefined) elem.__data__ = [];
  elem.__data__.push(d[1]);
});
```

This will bind the array of corresponding data items to each DOM element. Now you can use D3's [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) to create the nested elements:

```
d3.selectAll("div").selectAll("div")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("div")
  .html(function(d) { return d; });
```

Note the double `.selectAll("div")`; the first to select the existing elements and the second to select the (yet not existent) nested elements.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taq0ktu2/).

Answer (score -3):

use jquery istead it's much more supported and performant.
in Jquery you just have a look to traversing in 
this pretty good reference good reference :

Comment: It'd be great if you could put more information into your answer. E.g. code snippets addressing the problem of OP. For the future [How-to-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can give you some orientation on writing good answers.